# Troubleshooting s3 ajax uploader in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using: https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader with AWS backend (s3 boto). My file uploads are all 0 bytes, but they upload and the correct filename shows up on the correct bucket. Any thoughts on why the files are all 0 bytes though? I am looking for some higher level considerations.

Here's s3 backend code:
https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader/blob/master/ajaxuploader/backends/s3.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The s3 backend for this Ajax uploader is using MultiPart upload.  This will only work for files that are > 100MB and each part must be 5MB or larger.  So, I think what is happening is that it's initiating the Multipart upload and finalizing it but the individual parts are being rejected because they are too small.  So, the result is a zero-length file in S3.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you write to StringIO like that, it positions the file pointer at the end, and there is nothing to upload. You ought to do

```
buffer = StringIO(chunk)
```

Comment: I tried that and it still comes to 0 bytes. Thank you for the response though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I would try first to actually make the simplest possible chunked upload test using just plain boto, and thus see if the problem is with boto or something else.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered something like this. Try calling the method `seek(0)` on the file to set its current position back to the beginning.

Comment: my answer addresses that concern already. There is something else seriously broken.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, it seems so. When I change the backend to LocalStorage, it works perfectly.

Comment: Upvotes all around for your efforts and reasoning. Please let me know if you gain any additional insight. @AnttiHaapala and SeanConaty